# NN from scratch works with simple problems but not with MNIST numbers

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, regression

I have been working on a NN with one hidden layer with a flexible amount of nodes in each of the three layers. Here is the code:

```
import time
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import mnist

class_names = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']

class NeuralNetwork():

    correct = 0
    num_predictions = 10
    epochs = 100
    sizeOfEpoch = 5000
    Lambda = 10
    learningRate = 0.00001

    def __init__(self, sizes):
        self.dimensions = sizes

        self.x = np.arange(1,self.epochs+1)
        self.y = np.empty(self.epochs)

        self.secondLayerNeurons = np.empty(sizes[1])
        self.outputNeurons = np.empty(sizes[2])

        self.firstLayerWeights = np.random.rand(sizes[1], sizes[0])
        self.secondLayerWeights = np.random.rand(sizes[2], sizes[1])
        self.firstLayerBiases = np.random.rand(sizes[1])
        self.secondLayerBiases = np.random.rand(sizes[2])

        self.firstLayerWeightsSummations = np.zeros([sizes[1], sizes[0]])
        self.secondLayerWeightsSummations = np.zeros([sizes[2], sizes[1]])
        self.firstLayerBiasesSummations = np.zeros([sizes[1]])
        self.secondLayerBiasesSummations = np.zeros([sizes[2]])

        self.hiddenLayerErrors = np.empty(sizes[1])
        self.outputLayerErrors = np.empty(sizes[2])

    def sigmoid(self, x):
        return 1/(1+np.exp(-x))

    def sigmoidDerivative(self, x):
        return np.multiply(x,(1-x))

    def forwardProp(self, inputs):
        for i in range (self.dimensions[1]):
            self.secondLayerNeurons[i] = self.sigmoid(np.dot(self.firstLayerWeights[i], inputs)+self.firstLayerBiases[i])
        for i in range (self.dimensions[2]):
            self.outputNeurons[i] = self.sigmoid(np.dot(self.secondLayerWeights[i], self.secondLayerNeurons)+self.secondLayerBiases[i])

    def backProp(self, inputs, correct_output):
        self.outputLayerErrors = np.subtract(self.outputNeurons, correct_output)
        self.hiddenLayerErrors = np.multiply(np.dot(self.secondLayerWeights.T, self.outputLayerErrors), self.sigmoidDerivative(self.secondLayerNeurons))

        for i in range (self.dimensions[2]):
            for j in range (self.dimensions[1]):
                if j==0:
                    self.secondLayerBiasesSummations[i] += self.outputLayerErrors[i]
                self.secondLayerWeightsSummations[i][j] += self.outputLayerErrors[i]*self.secondLayerNeurons[j]
        for i in range (self.dimensions[1]):
            for j in range (self.dimensions[0]):
                if j==0:
                    self.firstLayerBiasesSummations[i] += self.hiddenLayerErrors[i]
                self.firstLayerWeightsSummations[i][j] += self.hiddenLayerErrors[i]*inputs[j]

    def train(self, trainImages, trainLabels):
        size = str(self.sizeOfEpoch)
        greatestError = 0.0
        start_time2 = time.time()

        for m in range (self.sizeOfEpoch):
            correct_output = np.zeros([self.dimensions[2]])
            correct_output[int(class_names[trainLabels[m]])] = 1.0

            self.forwardProp(trainImages[m].flatten())
            self.backProp(trainImages[m].flatten(), correct_output)

            if np.argmax(self.outputNeurons) == int(trainLabels[m]):
                self.correct+=1

            if m%200 == 0:
                error = np.amax(np.absolute(self.outputLayerErrors))
                if error > greatestError:
                    greatestError = error
                accuracy = str(int((self.correct/(m+1))*100)) + '%'
                percent = str(int((m/self.sizeOfEpoch)*100)) + '%'
                print ("Progress: " + percent + " -- Accuracy: " + accuracy + " -- Error: " + str(greatestError), end="\r")
        self.change()

        time2 = str(round((time.time() - start_time2), 2))
        print (size + '/' + size + " -- " + time2 + "s" + " -- Accuracy: " + accuracy + " -- Error: " + str(greatestError), end="\r")
        return greatestError

    def change(self):
        for i in range (self.dimensions[2]):
            for j in range (self.dimensions[1]):
                if j == 0:
                    self.secondLayerBiases[i] -= self.learningRate*self.secondLayerBiasesSummations[i]
                self.secondLayerWeights[i][j] -= self.learningRate*(self.secondLayerWeightsSummations[i][j]+self.Lambda*self.secondLayerWeights[i][j])
        for i in range (self.dimensions[1]):
            for j in range (self.dimensions[0]):
                if j == 0:
                    self.firstLayerBiases[i] -= self.learningRate*self.firstLayerBiasesSummations[i]
                self.firstLayerWeights[i][j] -= self.learningRate*(self.firstLayerWeightsSummations[i][j]+self.Lambda*self.firstLayerWeights[i][j])

        self.firstLayerSummations = np.zeros([self.dimensions[1], self.dimensions[0]])
        self.secondLayerSummations = np.zeros([self.dimensions[2], self.dimensions[1]])
        self.firstLayerBiasesSummations = np.zeros(self.dimensions[1])
        self.secondLayerBiasesSummations = np.zeros(self.dimensions[2])
        self.correct = 0
            
    def predict(self, testImage):
        secondLayerAnsNodes = np.empty([self.dimensions[1]])
        outputAns = np.empty([self.dimensions[2]])
        for i in range (self.dimensions[1]):
            secondLayerAnsNodes[i] = self.sigmoid(np.dot(self.firstLayerWeights[i], testImage)+self.firstLayerBiases[i])
        for i in range (self.dimensions[2]):
            outputAns[i] = self.sigmoid(np.dot(self.secondLayerWeights[i], secondLayerAnsNodes)+self.secondLayerBiases[i])
        return np.argmax(outputAns)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    (train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = mnist.load_data()
    train_images = train_images/255.0
    test_images = test_images/255.0

    neural_network = NeuralNetwork([784, 16, 10])

    start_time = time.time()
    for i in range (neural_network.epochs):
        print ("\nEpoch", str(i+1) + "/" + str(neural_network.epochs))
        neural_network.y[i]=neural_network.train(train_images, train_labels)
    time = time.time() - start_time

    plt.plot(neural_network.x, neural_network.y, 'b')
    plt.ylabel('Error Change')
    plt.xlabel('Epochs')
    plt.show()

    print("\n\n\nTotal Time Used")
    if time/60 < 60:
        print("Minutes: %s" % round((time/60),2))
    else:
        print("Seconds: %s" % round(time,2))

    for i in range (neural_network.num_predictions):
        prediction = neural_network.predict(test_images[i].flatten())
        plt.grid(False)
        plt.imshow(test_images[i], cmap=plt.cm.binary)
        plt.title("Prediction: " + str(prediction) + " -- Actual: " + class_names[test_labels[i]] + "\n" + str(i+1) + "/" + str(neural_network.num_predictions))
        plt.show()
```

For some reason, this code does not work with more complicated problems. The error doesn't get minimized and the accuracy stays the same. This exact code works for the xor problem and another one similar to it. When I try and give it the MNIST dataset of numbers, it doesn't work. The only difference is that there are more nodes in each layer, the algorithm is the same.

What could be the problem here?

This is a graph after running 20 epochs with a learning rate of 0.000001 and a lambda of 10. It shows the error per epoch. The y label is supposed to say error, not error change.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLXzz.png

Comment: I'm confused about your loss function. You have `self.outputLayerErrors = np.subtract(self.outputNeurons, correct_output)`. This isn't a loss function; it can be arbitrarily negative, so it seems like minimizing it would arbitrarily encourage the outputNeurons to always converge toward zero (because 0 - correctOutput is the "smallest" loss you can get using this loss function). For a classification program, you might check into cross entropy loss. Basically, you interpret the output values as class probabilities and maximize the log likelihood for the correct class while minimizing the others

Comment: @Nerdizzle That isn't my loss function, that is part of my derivative of the loss function. That derivative is based on a video by Andrew Ng, the link is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x_Eamf8MHwU&list=PLLssT5z_DsK-h9vYZkQkYNWcItqhlRJLN&index=51 and the time is 7:52

Comment: I see, so the `outputLayerErrors` are not really output layer errors; they are actually the gradients of the cross entropy loss w.r.t. the output layer logits. With that understanding, I've examined your code and it looks okay. I suggest tweaking the learning rate (having too high of a learning rate for a given task will always make an mlp diverge). Try different orders of magnitude (e.g. 0.0001, 0.00001, and 0.000001). I'd also try increasing the number of hidden nodes. 10 seems to be very few. I will also try to tweak hyperparameters and see what I can do.

Comment: @Nerdizzle Thanks a lot for actually looking at my code, I'll try and adjust a few constants and see what happens! I added some code to plot the output errors and i''ll post that once it finishes training

Comment: I've finished my experiments. I ran them in the background throughout the day. See my posted answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing technically wrong with your implementation. However, there are a few things to note, all of which have significant impact on the performance you are seeing. This is a long answer, but each part reflects an important change that I made to your code to make it work as intended, so read it all carefully.

Firstly, you shouldn't initialize your weights in (0, 1), which is what `np.random.randn` does by default. Specifically, if you're going to choose uniform random weights, the uniform distribution should be centered at zero. For instance, choose random numbers in the range (-1, 1), or (-.1, .1). Otherwise, your MLP is immediately biased; many of the hidden layer neurons will immediately map to nearly 1 through the sigmoid activation. Afterall, the sigmoid activation is centered (along the x axis) at zero, so your default inputs should be as well. This problem can very easily prevent your MLP from converging at all (and, in fact, it does in your case). There are better weight initialization methods than sampling from a uniform random distribution, but that is not to say that this method will not work if done properly.

Secondly, you should probably normalize the image data. Neural networks don't do great with inputs between 0 and 255, which is how the image data is exported from keras by default. You can fix this by just dividing each input feature by 255. The reason for this is that the sigmoid curve has very small derivatives at high-magnitude subdomains. In other words, when x is very large or very small (very negative), the derivative of sigmoid(x) w.r.t x is very nearly zero. When you're multiplying some weights by very large values (such as 255), then you are likely to get into this high-magnitude domain of the sigmoid curve right off the bat. This won't necessarily prevent your net from converging, but it'll certainly slow it down in the beginning since small derivatives result in small gradients, which in turn result in small weight updates. You could increase the learning rate, but that might result in the neural network overstepping (and possibly diverging) once it gets out of the low-derivative areas of the sigmoid curve. Again, I have tested (and fixed) this problem in your specific program, and it does make a significant difference (final accuracies around .8 as opposed to .6).

Next, your way of calculating an "error" is a bit strange. It computes the largest error over the entire epoch and prints it. The largest error of an epoch is hardly a useful error metric; even a very well-designed, well-trained, deep convolutional neural network will occasionally perform poorly on at least one datapoint throughout an epoch. Your accuracy measure is probably decent enough for getting a gauge of how well your model is converging. However, I also added an "average error" by simply adapting your current error calculation. Since you're using cross entropy loss (at least, this is true given your method of calculating gradients), I'd recommend writing a function which *actually* computes a cross entropy loss (sum of negative log likelihoods in your case). Keep in mind when interpreting such a loss that the negative log likelihood over a sigmoid is bounded in (0, infinity), and so cross entropy loss is as well.

Of course, another issue is likely the learning rate. In fact, most would argue that the learning rate is the most important hyperparameter to tune. I ended up using `0.00001`, though I didn't do much of a grid search.

Next, you are using full batch learning. This means that you compute a sum of gradients over every single data point, and then you update your weights once. In other words, you only perform one weight update per epoch. If that's the case, you're going to have to do a lot of epochs to get decent results. If you have the time and computational resources, that's probably fine. However, if you don't, you might consider mini-batch. Mini-batch is still fairly robust to sample order (though you theoretically should still shuffle the data for each epoch), at least compared to online / stochastic learning. It involves dividing your full dataset into "batches" of some predefined size. For each batch, you compute the sum of the model gradients over each data point in the batch. Then, you do a weight update (by calling `change()`). Once you've gone over every batch, that constitutes a single epoch. I used minibatch and a batch size of 1,000.

Lastly (and I want to say most importantly, but the other things I've mentioned are also preventing convergence), you are not training on all the training data (8,000 / 60,000); you are not training for enough epochs (5 is not likely to be enough, especially when you're only training on a fraction of the data); and your model is likely too simple (not enough hidden layer nodes). However, the overarching issue is that the implementation does not always make use of vectorized operations when appropriate, and thus it is far too slow to actually train on all of the training data with a sufficient number epochs and model complexity.

I updated your implementation (most notably `backprop()` and `change()`) to make use of numpy's vectorized operations whenever possible. This sped the implementation up by several orders of magnitude. However, I don't believe it inherently changed the semantics of your code at all. I've also implemented the other changes I suggested throughout this post. I'm getting about 85% training accuracy on average (though it varies +/- 6% by batch) after just 20 epochs and only 32 hidden nodes in the hidden layer. I did not run it against the test set, and so I did not mess with the regularization parameter either (I simply set `Lambda` to zero). Here is the updated code (I redacted parts, such as the `predict()` function, for brevity):

```
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import mnist

class_names = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']

class NeuralNetwork():

    correct = 0
    epochs = 20
    Lambda = 0
    learningRate = 0.00001

    def __init__(self, sizes, batchSize):
        self.batchSize = batchSize
        self.dimensions = sizes

        self.secondLayerNeurons = np.empty(sizes[1])
        self.outputNeurons = np.empty(sizes[2])

        # Draw weights and biases from (-1, 1) by multiplying the (0, 1)
        # values by 2 and subtracting 1. There are better ways of doing this,
        # but this works just fine.
        self.firstLayerWeights = np.random.rand(sizes[1], sizes[0]) * 2 - 1
        self.secondLayerWeights = np.random.rand(sizes[2], sizes[1]) * 2 - 1
        self.firstLayerBiases = np.random.rand(sizes[1]) * 2 - 1
        self.secondLayerBiases = np.random.rand(sizes[2]) * 2 - 1

        self.firstLayerWeightsSummations = np.zeros([sizes[1], sizes[0]])
        self.secondLayerWeightsSummations = np.zeros([sizes[2], sizes[1]])
        self.firstLayerBiasesSummations = np.zeros([sizes[1]])
        self.secondLayerBiasesSummations = np.zeros([sizes[2]])

        self.hiddenLayerErrors = np.empty(sizes[1])
        self.outputLayerErrors = np.empty(sizes[2])

    def sigmoid(self, x):
        return 1/(1+np.exp(-x))

    def sigmoidDerivative(self, x):
        return np.multiply(x,(1-x))


    def forwardProp(self, inputs):
        for i in range (self.dimensions[1]):
            self.secondLayerNeurons[i] = self.sigmoid(np.dot(self.firstLayerWeights[i], inputs)+self.firstLayerBiases[i])
        for i in range (self.dimensions[2]):
            self.outputNeurons[i] = self.sigmoid(np.dot(self.secondLayerWeights[i], self.secondLayerNeurons)+self.secondLayerBiases[i])

    def backProp(self, inputs, correct_output):
        self.outputLayerErrors = np.subtract(self.outputNeurons, correct_output)
        self.hiddenLayerErrors = np.multiply(np.dot(self.secondLayerWeights.T, self.outputLayerErrors), self.sigmoidDerivative(self.secondLayerNeurons))

        self.secondLayerBiasesSummations += self.outputLayerErrors
        self.secondLayerWeightsSummations += np.outer(self.outputLayerErrors, self.secondLayerNeurons)

        self.firstLayerBiasesSummations += self.hiddenLayerErrors
        self.firstLayerWeightsSummations += np.outer(self.hiddenLayerErrors, inputs)

    def train(self, trainImages, trainLabels):
        size = str(self.batchSize)
        err_sum = 0.0
        err_count = 0
        avg_err = 0.0

        for m in range (self.batchSize):
            correct_output = np.zeros([self.dimensions[2]])
            correct_output[trainLabels[m]] = 1.0

            self.forwardProp(trainImages[m].flatten())
            self.backProp(trainImages[m].flatten(), correct_output)

            if np.argmax(self.outputNeurons) == int(trainLabels[m]):
                self.correct+=1

            if m%150 == 0:
                error = np.amax(np.absolute(self.outputLayerErrors))
                err_sum += error
                err_count += 1
                avg_err = err_sum / err_count
                accuracy = str(int((self.correct/(m+1))*100)) + '%'
                percent = str(int((m/self.batchSize)*100)) + '%'
                print ("Progress: " + percent + " -- Accuracy: " + accuracy + " -- Error: " + str(avg_err), end="\r")

        self.change()
        print (size + '/' + size + " -- " + " -- Accuracy: " + accuracy + " -- Error: " + str(avg_err), end="\r")
        self.correct = 0

    def change(self):

        self.secondLayerBiases -= self.learningRate * self.secondLayerBiasesSummations
        self.secondLayerWeights -= self.learningRate * self.secondLayerWeightsSummations
        self.firstLayerBiases -= self.learningRate * self.firstLayerBiasesSummations
        self.firstLayerWeights -= self.learningRate * self.firstLayerWeightsSummations

        self.firstLayerSummations = np.zeros([self.dimensions[1], self.dimensions[0]])
        self.secondLayerSummations = np.zeros([self.dimensions[2], self.dimensions[1]])
        self.firstLayerBiasesSummations = np.zeros(self.dimensions[1])
        self.secondLayerBiasesSummations = np.zeros(self.dimensions[2])

if __name__ == "__main__":

    (train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = mnist.load_data()
    train_images = train_images / 255 # Normalize image data

    num_using = 60000 # Amount of data points to use. It's fast now, so we may as well use the full 60,000
    bs = 1000 # Batch size. 60,000 is full batch. Consider trying mini-batch
    neural_network = NeuralNetwork([784, 32, 10], bs)

    for i in range (neural_network.epochs):
        print ("\nEpoch", str(i+1) + "/" + str(neural_network.epochs))
        for j in range(int(num_using / bs)):
            print("Batch", str(j+1) + "/" + str(int(60000 / bs)))
            neural_network.train(train_images[int(j * bs):int(j * bs) + bs], train_labels[int(j * bs):int(j * bs) + bs])
```

For further improvements requiring minimal effort, I'd suggest trying even more hidden nodes (perhaps even 128), further tweaking the learning rate and regularization parameter, trying different batch sizes, and tweaking the number of epochs.

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thank you so much for spending this much time on this. This is my first neural network and you helped A LOT! I didn't know where else to get help since I'm only in high school. BTW, did I mention how much you helped me?

Comment: A few questions about the implementation I had were what is the best size range of the batch size and how would I vectorize the change function if I add a regularization term. I worry that if the batch size is too small, the gradient descent might not be correct. In the future, is there a general way to figure what the problem with my code is or is tweaking every constant the only approach? Again, thanks a lot.

Comment: The best batch size is highly sensitive to the problem domain (task, dataset, etc.) as well as the other hyperparameters you use. There is no one best batch size; you'll have to play around with it to find what works best. As for vectorizing the regularization, remember that the point of regularization is simply to encourage the weights to have small magnitudes. You should be able to do this generally like so (L2 regularization): `self.firstLayerWeights -= self.learningRate * (self.firstLayerWeightsSummations + self.Lambda * self.firstLayerWeights)`. I have not tested this, however.

Comment: Is there any way to get better accuracy and lower cost? I have been playing around with the constants and I can't get better accuracy than 85%. Is there anything that I can add or change? This should be the last question I have so thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: You might ask yourself what sort of accuracy you expect to get and why your accuracy is lower. If your model is underfitting, you may need to add complexity to your model (e.g. more hidden nodes). However, this is at a higher cost. If it's overfitting, you might try different regularization techniques. If you want better results with the same model complexity, you'll need some model constraints specifically designed for image recognition, like convolutional layers. You may also try image preprocessing to get better results for little cost. Ultimately, an MLP can only do so much with images.

Comment: You might also try Relu activations in the hidden layer instead of sigmoids. This is pretty easy to do. You could also try a different optimization algorithm like Adam (rather than vanilla gradient descent). This is a bit more work.